# Print output in a column

Tags: python

```
average = total / words
zs      = words / lines

print("BLABLABLA: ", round(average))
print("BLABLA: ", round(zs))
```

How can I print tho's two outputs exactly under each other? (%d??)

Help please

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) method :

```
print("BLABLABLA: {: >10}".format(round(average)))
print("BLABLA: {: >10}".format(round(zs)))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `: >10` within the braces?

Comment: @DavidZemens Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects). Read the more document in link